How do i run script3 even though the chmod u+x command is not giving it permission on my ubuntu
I want to give script3 permission so i typed in cd/home/dela/Desktop
chmod u+x script3
Itsays;chmod;cannotaccessscript3':Nosuchfiledirectory.
so i typed in;
/home/dela/script3
Itsays:permission denied
then i typed ;
cd/home/dela/Desktop
chmod +x script3.sh(after renaming script3)
same issue
I pasted the content of script3 on chat gpt it said there are no issues with the text itself.

Should be a space between cd and /home...,like this cd /home/...
